# "Integer" for digits?

Tags: java

Really stupid question, but what's the relevant to integer for letters. 
This is an example - when I write 1, the console prints 2. What I want to do is instead of using numbers, to use letters. For example when I write "a" it prints "b", as int num only allows me to use numbers .. for obvious reasons. Sorry about the question again, really new into Java.

```
int num1;
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("First number");
     num1 = input.nextInt();

 if (num1 == 1);
 {
     System.out.println("2");
 }
```

Comment: `Scanner#nextLine()`?

Comment: Are you always just returning one "more" than the input?

Comment: Are you asking how to increment a letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can be more clear ı can help but this is what ı understood about your question. hope it helps

```
    String str;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("First letter ");
    str = input.next();

    if (str.equals("a"))

    {
        System.out.println("b");

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The JavaDocs are really helpful in situations like this (google "javadoc Scanner" for example).  If we look through the methods provided by scanner we find `nextInt()` which you already know about, but we also find `next()` which returns a `String` and says it "*Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.*"  Well, that seems helpful, `next()` does seem to be the kind of thing we are looking for.

```
String s = input.next();
```

Now, how to get at the first character in `s`.   You guessed in (google "javasoc String").  Right at the top we find `charAt()` which seems perfect:

```
char c = s.charAt(0);
```

now you can see what is in `c`:

```
if (c == 'a') {
    /* do something */
}
```